# Angular : Bootstrap - How can I use full height In a component while calling from other component?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

In my Angular app, I have two components : the `app.component` (which is always by default created) and the `login.component`.

I am calling `login.component` from `app.component`. But the problem is I am not getting full height when designing something inside login component. As a result, when I call `login.component` from `app.component`, the design is very less in height than I expect.

So how can I use full height at my 2nd component when I call it from first component?

**app.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" >Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" >Create</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" >Display</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" >Report</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>

</html>
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div style="height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: #44739d; ">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; height: 100%;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username / Email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Notes:

1)As you can see, I marked the whole page blue, My 2nd component (login) is using only upper part of the page

2)In my 2nd component, I am using style="height:100%" still not working. (After this, I have a feeling like something from 1st component is blocking the height of 2nd component, but see the next point)

3)So I am checking back my first component, In body there is only a **bootstrap** `nav-bar` and an **angular** `<router-outlet>` . `nav-bar` is OK, it is supposed to be on top and shouldn't affect my design. I also tried removing it, the problem is same . Now did I do any mistake calling the `<router-outlet>`?

There should be a simple fix, What I am missing?

[ By the way, there is no .ts code added (except the built-in codes) , I was just designing with `HTML` and `ng-bootstrap` alone]

Answer (score 1):

Just add a container or container-fluid class inside your HTML.

```
<div class="container-fuild">  
<router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div>
```

or you can add container or container-fluid to your body like below

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <--- your content here --->

  </div>
</body>
```

Refer:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers